# Ready event for dynamic add polymer elements

Tags: javascript, polymer, polymer-1.0, web-component

How do I know when a polymer element is ready? Giving that:

It is dynamically added, as:

```
var ele = document.createElement('my-custom-element');
document.body.appendChild(ele);
```

So now when I call `ele.myCustomMethod()` it will fail because it is not ready yet (in FF/IE/Safari with webcomponent-lite.js)

What I am doing right now is call `this.fire('ready')` inside the polymer element `ready()` function, and listen to it `ele.addEventListener('ready', ()=>{ele.myCustomMethod();})`

But this make all code very hard to write. And sometimes I use `$(body).html('<my-custom-element />')`, and it make things more complicated.

**My question is:** Is there any better way to do that?

Thank you.

Comment: When you say `ele.myCustomMethod()` will fail, does it fail because it is undefined or is the problem within that function?

Comment: @Kable : It failed because it is undefined. It is undefined because, I believe,  google polymer (or webcomponent polyfill) hasn't finish initializing it yet.

Comment: did you find an answer? Your solution is the same I came up with and I'm also not very hapy about it.

Comment: @three sorry no :(

Comment: @garyx I found an emitted event in my element which I'm using now. But that doesn't help you.

Answer (score -2):

You can try listening for the WebComponentsReady event on the window first.

Source: https://github.com/webcomponents/webcomponentsjs#webcomponentsready

Comment: Thanks. I did listen to that. But the problem in the questions is when I add the element on the fly. I don't think it re-fire the 'WebComponentsReady' event again